# Pad each outer level index of a DF with rows of zeros so that all of these outer indices have the same shape

Tags: python, pandas

Say I have a DF in the following format:

```
             col1   col2
idx1 idx2          
   A    W       2      6
        X       5      8
        Y       7      6 
        Z       5      3
   B    X       2      1
        Y       6      5
   C    W       3      4
        X       9      4
        Y       5      3
```

I want to pad B and C of idx1 so that they have the same number of rows as A of idx1:

```
             col1   col2
idx1 idx2          
   A    W       2      6
        X       5      8
        Y       7      6 
        Z       5      3
   B    X       2      1
        Y       6      5
        0       0      0 
        0       0      0
   C    W       3      4
        X       9      4
        Y       5      3
        0       0      0
```

The index names of the added rows do not matter.

This is what I have tried:

```
blank = pd.DataFrame([0, 0]), index=df.columns).T
for ID in IDs:
    for _ in range(maxLength - lengths[ID]):
        df.loc[ID] = df.loc[ID].append(blank)
```

where:

- `blank` is a single row of zeros
- `IDs` is `['A', 'B', 'C']`
- `maxLength` = 4 (the number of rows in `df.loc['A']`
- `lengths` is a dict of `{'A': 4, 'B': 2, 'C': 3}`

This results in `df.loc['A']` staying as it is, but `df.loc['B']` and `df.loc['C']` keep their original shape but are now populated entirely with `NaN`s. I presume it is a problem with trying to assign a new, different shaped DF at each call of `df.loc[ID] = ...`

Comment: df.unstack(fill_value=0).stack()

Comment: @Wen that works perfectly for the original example I gave. However, in my actual data set, the inner indices don't all start at the same value, and so this pads the beginning rows where this is the case. See my revised example - particularly how `df.loc['B']` has inner indices starting at `X`, not `W`. Is this possible?